# why my AWS Lighsail hosting down eveeyday?

Tags: wordpress, web-hosting, amazon-lightsail, cloud-hosting

I Hosted a WordPress ecommerce website on AWs LightSail on free tier with 512mb ram 1vcpu 22gb ssd storage. But Everyday my site down and showing error database connection and also show error host 524.
Then I stop the instance and again start then my site working. Everyday I do the same. But I can not find what is the actual reason for this problem.[click to view error showing like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0BXs.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking your web server, mail, PHP & database logs as the first step. There is something triggering the timeout on your server.

I had a recent job recently and Error 524 was popping out due to wrong Sendmail configuration. Whenever admin created a user or a new post, the website timed out due to Sendmail trying to unsuccessfully send an e-mail in the background.